# Woocommerce Rest Api: Creating order does not return checkout url

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api

Hi i have Api Developer role in a team.
when i manually click on 'Proceed to checkout' Button & get List of All Oders using Orders Api using Postman i can see checkout url in response in meta_data value

```
"meta_data": [{
                "id": 4450301,
                "key": "mailchimp_woocommerce_campaign_id",
                "value": ""
            },
            {
                "id": 4450302,
                "key": "mailchimp_woocommerce_landing_site",
                "value": "https://firewallforce.se/checkout/order-pay/443614/?key=wc_order_o9LVuBKCMnKP6"
            }]
```

But when i create order using create order Api here in docs

```
https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#create-an-order
```

instead of clicking checkout button i dont see any checkout url in response.key exists but value empty in meta data. My role is api developer & am not supposed to click manually.i
am stuck for days please help me. thanks in advance

Comment: Please add more data like which API you called and API which executed when clicked on 'Proceed to checkout'?

Comment: i dont know which checkout button is on woocommerce website.
but i can tell create order api am using

Comment: Do you want to make an action like 'Proceed to checkout' with your created order on API? If yes, the #create-an-order API was processed. So you don't need to execute it any more.

Comment: i am creating Api in expressjs i need to send checkout url to client side for frontend developer

Comment: Unfortunately, the woocommerce API doesn't support cart endpoints, you have to handle it on expressjs manually.
Or you can use https://github.com/co-cart/co-cart plugin to integrate with Woocommerce API and use its API to handle the cart.

Comment: i have api which add/remove products in cart.but that does not generate checkout page.